# ido-completing-read interaction with _ and -, hides possible results

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, ido-mode

When using `ido-completing-read`

```
(ido-completing-read "Which tag: " '("DALL-E" "monoidallens") nil t)
```

it finds both tags when I type "`dall`" but once I enter "`dalle`" it no longer finds "`DALL-E`"

```
Which tag: dall{DALL-E | monoidallens}
Which tag: dalle[monoidallens]
```

Whereas if I add an underscore to the "`monoidal_lens`" tag

```
(ido-completing-read "Which tag: " '("DALL-E" "monoidal_lens") nil t)
```

the input "`dall`" only matches "`DALL-E`" and while the input "`dalle`" matches both.

```
Which tag: dall[DALL-E]
Which tag: dalle{DALL-E | monoidal_lens}
```

Why does this happen? Is there a way to show all possible suggestions, adding more characters should not make suggestions go away.

Comment: On the second example, "dalle" matches nothing on my side, which is consistent with the first.

Comment: To customize the completion behavior, You can take a look at `completion-styles-alist` and orderless to choose the style you like.